# Knockoutjs binding not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an array, which I single out an item, change the data, but I don't see the change in the binding.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div data-bind="text: age">
   </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function ContainerVM() {
   var self = this;
   self.persons = ko.observableArray();
   self.persons.push({
      name: 'John',
      age: 30
   });
   self.persons.push({
      name: 'Jane',
      age: 40
   });
   self.selectedPerson = ko.observable(undefined);
   self.age = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.selectedPerson() === undefined ? 0 : self.selectedPerson().age;
   }, this);
}

var vm = new ContainerVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container"));

vm.selectedPerson(vm.persons()[0]);

console.log(vm.persons()[0]);

vm.selectedPerson().age = 50;

console.log(vm.persons()[0]);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/ex05eun5/3/)

When I change the age to 50, I expect the `<div data-bind="text: age">` to change to 50, but it doesn't.

Console.log of persons shows, that the persons item has changed to 50.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ex05eun5/4/

Basically the problem is that when only a property of an item in an array changes, the DOM will not be updated. The solution is to create the array of observable elements. Creating an `ObservablePerson` does exactly that.

```
var ObservablePerson = function(name, age){
    var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.age = ko.observable(age);
}
```

So when you push elements to the array, you can do it as follows:

```
self.persons.push(new ObservablePerson(
    'John',
    30
));
```

And modify them as follows:

```
vm.selectedPerson().age(50);
```

Here's what the official documentation has to say about that:

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Ah ok ... I learned something new ... thanks. Loving Knockoutjs more and more .... thanks a million for helping me out!!!!